# How to use a variable for the configuration in a dependencies block?

Tags: gradle

I would like to do something like:

```
  dependencies {
    final c = (someCondition ? compile : providedCompile)
    c 'example:example:1.+'
  }
```

But that runs into an error about `compile` and `providedCompile` not being known. How can something like that be done?

The following also doesn't do what I would expect:

```
configurations {
  c.extendsFrom (someCondition ? configurations.compile : configurations.providedCompile)
}

dependencies {
  c 'example:example:1.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the following works:

```
  final c = (someCondition ? 'compile' : 'providedCompile')
  "${ideDependentConfiguration}" …
```